# React Material UI DataGrid: Cannot read property 'useRef' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, cross-browser

**The problem**

I am trying to use the [React DataGrid](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/getting-started/). But I am getting a stacktrace in the browser where it caughts a TypeError: Cannot read property 'useRef' of undefined. [image: StackTrace error]

**What have I tried**

I have tried using different versions of the React DataGrid. Also I have tried different versions of React Core / Styles.

**Where do I think the underlaying issue is**

I think it has something to do with the Parcel Bundler. A colleague does not experience this issue and he is using react-scripts.

**What am I using**

I am just using the example code from the official documentation. Which looks like below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './HomePage.scss';
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid';

const rows = [
    { id: 1, col1: 'Hello', col2: 'World' },
    { id: 2, col1: 'XGrid', col2: 'is Awesome' },
    { id: 3, col1: 'Material-UI', col2: 'is Amazing' },
];

const columns = [
    { field: 'col1', headerName: 'Column 1', width: 150 },
    { field: 'col2', headerName: 'Column 2', width: 150 },
];

export default class HomePage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{ height: 300, width: '100%' }}>
                <DataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So I think my packages are more important. I listed the important ones below.

```
"@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
"@material-ui/core": "5.0.0-alpha.30",
"@material-ui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.30",
"parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
"@types/react": "^17.0.0",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
```

Any insights are welcome. Did someone else manage to get Material UI working with Parcel. If yes, which versions do you use?

**Update**

I am getting the suggestion to use version 4.12.3 of material-ui core. However, the problem still appears. The versions I am using right now are:

```
"@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.37",
"@material-ui/core": "4.12.3",
"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.58",
```

**Steps to reproduce**

- Clone/download [Repo](https://github.com/Daanholsink/Material-UI-bug)
- Navigate to the folder
- npm install
- npm start

Comment: down grade the version of @material-ui/core to 4.12.3 and @matrial-ui/lab 4.0.0-alpha version, after doing this it will work.

Comment: @SunnyGoel Thanks for the response. I just tried your suggestion and now I am getting a different message. Cannot resolve module 'react'.

Comment: can you add that error message over here

Comment: @SunnyGoel I restarted my IDE. I did test with your suggestion but I am still getting "Cannot read property useRef of undefined".

Comment: I have added my new versions to the post itself. The error still occurs though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by updating parcel to version 2.

So I removed >

```
"parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"
```

And I added >

```
"parcel": "^2.0.0-rc.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce your @material-ui/core to `4.12.3`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunaly the error still occurs.

Comment: I have added my new versions to the post itself. The error still occurs though.

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same. I will add a cloneable repo to the question in a couple minutes.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox and share the link here?

Comment: Somehow the code works in codesandbox. But not in a brand new parcel bundler project. I have no idea where the underlaying problem is. I did add a cloneable repo to this post.

Comment: Do you have any public repo for this project?